# asking for a good way to go: displaying data collected by some kind of windows service in html

Tags: c#, html, web-services, wcf, service

to put it in a nutshell:

- I need to write some kind of windows service that collects data via a simple tcp/ip protocol
- the collected data should be displayed on other computers inside the local area network using html/webbrowser
- it should be possible to send commands/data from the viewer/webbrowser to the service
- data displayed at the viewer should be refreshed if it changes. if that's not possible, polling would be also ok.

I'm using C# Visual Studio 2015.
By now the data is collected by a windows forms application (exe) and I think I can reuse some of the code (i.e. the classes for the simple tcp/ip protocol).
I already tried 'this and that', but the more I try, the more confused I am: should I use a WCF serive? WebService? REST? SOAP? Which concept is up to date, which one is outdated?

I would be very thankful if someone could give a direction what way would be good to go.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use selfhosted `ASP .NET WEB API` in your `WindowsService`.
This works fine and is easy to implement.